# How to fix my infinite loop while first fetching my data using Websockets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm doing a basic chat application which requires me to use websockets with socket.io, my problem is that I'm kinda a noobie in this field and don't really have any idea about how I should architecture it in my frontend.

This caused me to create an anoying bug which is that I'm stuck in an infinite loop of websockets calls (firing an infinite amount of time my once function).

Could you explain me what is wrong in what I did, and if you have any other advices of architecture (less uses of useEffects, refacto ...) I'm really opened to it.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useContext } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { ChatComponent } from '../../components/Chat/ChatComponent';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { UserContext } from '../../contexts/UserContext';
import getUserIdFromToken from '../../utils/user/getUserIdFromToken';
import transformApiResponse from '../../utils/message/transformApiResponse';
export interface ChatForm {
  newMessage: string;
}

export interface Message {
  username: string;
  userId: string;
  message: string;
}

export interface ApiMessage {
  id: string;
  message: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
  sender: User;
}

interface User {
  id: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  roles: UserRole[];
  password: string;
}

type UserRole = 'USER';

export const Chat = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[]>([]);
  const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm<ChatForm>();
  const {token} = useContext(UserContext);
  const userId = getUserIdFromToken(token);
  const socket = io(':3001');
  const roomName = 'default';

  const receiveMessage = useCallback((message: Message | ApiMessage[]) => {
    //Check if message is of type ApiMessage
    if (Array.isArray(message)) {
      const transformedMessages = transformApiResponse(message);
      setMessages(transformedMessages);
      return;
    }

    setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, message]);
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = useCallback(({newMessage}: ChatForm) => {
    socket.emit('createMessage', {
      userId: userId,
      message: newMessage,
      roomName,
    });
  }, [socket, userId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('newMessage', receiveMessage);

    return () => {
      socket.off('newMessage', receiveMessage);
    };
  }, [receiveMessage, socket]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit('joinRoom', roomName);
    socket.emit('findAllMessageByRoom', roomName);
    socket.once('getAllMessage', receiveMessage);

    return () => {
      socket.off('getAllMessage', receiveMessage);
      socket.emit('leaveRoom', roomName);
    }
  }, [socket, roomName, receiveMessage]);

  return (
    <ChatComponent
      messages={messages}
      handleSubmit={handleSubmit(sendMessage)}
      register={register}
      userId={userId}
    />
  );
};
```

I tried to change receive message as an arrow function to delete messages dependency but it didn't work